# AngularJS get request not returning data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I Have the following code in which I'm trying to get a `JSON` file and attach its contents to my $scope.

The first `console.log` returns the result that I need, but the second returns `undefined`.

What would be the correct way to write this so that the data is stored?

```
'use strict';

var myApp = angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
    templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
    controller: 'View1Ctrl'
  });
}]);


myApp.controller('View1Ctrl', [

  '$scope',
  '$http',

  function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('view1/info.json')
    .then(function(res){
      $scope.data = res.data.info
      console.log($scope.data)
    });

    console.log($scope.data)
}]);
```

Comment: The data is being stored (in the controller scope)....but not until after your last `console.log()` runs because `$http` is asynchronous and takes time to complete. What exactly are you wanting to do.

Comment: I'm wanting to grab the json file and then store its info in $scope so I can use it in functions and put some of the content in a view

Comment: You can use it in view the way your code is set up now. If it's not working in view then problem is in view code or not understanding data structure properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is with something called Promises. I definitely suggets looking into them. Here is kind of what happens in order:

```
$http.get('view1/info.json')
```

That tells javascript I want to get the JSON data. But it does not actually get it yet. Then,  it does that console log.

```
console.log($scope.data)
```

Well $scope.data is undefined. Nothing has set it yet! Then, javascript actually gets the JSON data. When it gets the data, the function within the `then` is called. After this,

```
$scope.data = res.data.info
console.log($scope.data)
```

`$scope.data` is defined, which is why this `console.log` works. Read more about promises for more info!

Here is a good starting point: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wA0gZnBI8i4

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, I understand it  lot better now. Thanks for the link too

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS's [`$http.get()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)'s `then()` callback is called asynchronously.

That means that in the callback, it will work, but not in the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your data is stored. But not at the time your second console.log() gets executed. The "then" promise/callback will run *after* your second console.log(). If you need $scope.data in your templates, this should work. Angulars digest cycle will be run after the callback of $https.